# In inverting amplifiers, isn't the virtual earth approximation only valid for extremely high gains?

Tags: electricity, voltage

In this example, at point A, the voltage is +15V, so it is not at all a virtual earth. Then why is it that if we consider an arbitrary inverting amplifier circuit, apply the virtual earth approximation to get Vout / Vin = -R2/R1, and we then choose values of R2/R1 to give a low gain, our results are correct? 
I'm finding the argument for point A being at a virtual earth rather circular. 
I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this in a clear way. The problem I have with the general argument is that we say if the gain is large, then the formula we derive will be correct. But that formula itself controls the gain..

Another question I have is why do we define the gain of an inverting amplifier to be V output / V in? Should it not be V output / Potential difference between inverting and non-inverting terminals?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this example, at point A, the voltage is +15V, so it is not at all
>   a virtual earth.

*No*, it's *not* +15V.

The non-inverting terminal is at zero volts according to the circuit diagram.

Since there is negative feedback, and assuming the op-amp is ideal, it follows that the inverting terminal is also at zero volts (otherwise the output voltage would be 'infinite').

It's not clear whether node A is the non-inverting terminal or the inverting terminal but it doesn't matter, as your circuit is drawn, both are at zero volts.

---

*What if the op-amp is not ideal and has finite open-loop gain $A_{OL}$?*

Then we cannot enforce the constraint that the inverting terminal voltage equals the non-inverting terminal voltage.  But the analysis is still straightforward.

The voltage at the inverting terminal can be written by inspection:

$$v_- = \frac{v_{in} R_2 + v_{out} R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

But

$$v_{out} = A_{OL}(v_+ - v_-) = -A_{OL}\,v_-$$

and so

$$v_- =  \frac{v_{in} R_2 - v_- A_{OL}R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \Rightarrow v_- = v_{in}\frac{R_2}{(1 + A_{OL})R_1 + R_2}$$

thus

$$v_{out} = -v_{in}\frac{A_{OL}R_2}{(1 + A_{OL})R_1 + R_2}$$

Note that in the large $A_{OL}$ limit,

$$v_- \rightarrow 0$$

$$v_{out}\rightarrow -v_{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1}$$

as desired.

Comment: You might note that, in general, input offset voltages will be much higher than the gain error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the open loop gain of the op-amp itself (i.e. the gain if there is no feedback resistor), with the gain of the inverting op-amp circuit.

With no feedback the output is
$$V_o = G_o(V_+ - V_-)\,,$$
where $G_o$ is the open loop gain. For an ideal op-amp \$G_o\$ is infinity, for a real one it is very high (\$\sim 10^5)\$.

Now if we want to build an amplifier which doesn't have a gain of \$10^5\$ we put a feedback resistor in from the output to the negative terminal, this feedback resistor acts to balance the two inputs. In the circuit above the positive terminal is ground so as \$G_o \rightarrow \infty\$, \$A\rightarrow\$ ground. Now this **circuit** (not the op-amp itself) has a gain of 
$$G = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}\,.$$
Where the circuit gain is defined as
$$G = \frac{V_\mathrm{out}}{V_\mathrm{in}}\,.
$$

Comment: @Saad this and the others are correct.  ONLY when Vout is linear (ie. between max swing)  Vin+=Vin- is always true except for minor offsets incl. Vio which are only significant for high precision or high gain.   The high gain with feedback ensures this Vin+=Vin- as a differential error amplifier.. Thus if Vin+= gnd then Vin- is a virtually the same (gnd). If Vin+ was 1V then Vin- would be the same 1V..... make sense? that's why G or Av- as it is sometimes called from the -ve input G = -R2/R1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Electronics SE would be a better home for this question. As an exercise, try replacing the ideal amplifier with an ideal voltage amplifier with a finite gain, and examine how your equations behave as the gain becomes infinite. This exercise should give you insight into the idea of a "virtual" ground.

The reason that the gain is not defined to be \$V_{out}\$ divided by the potential difference between the non-inverting terminals is that this latter quantity is simply very high and varies a great deal between different manufactured amplifiers. So it's effectively undefined. The whole point of negative feedback is to render the poorly controlled, but large, amplifier gain unimportant in setting the whole circuit's gain. Refer to the results of your exercise above: the amplifier's gain can be any large number as long as it is much greater than the circuit's overall gain and the impact on the circuit's overall gain will be small.  The amplifier can even be quite nonlinear - as long as \$\mathrm{d} V_{out}/\mathrm{d} V_{+-}\$ is big enough, the nonlinearity will make little difference to the overall circuit's performance.